# unable to establish two way communication using qt

Tags: qt, sockets

I have used QTcpSocket and QTcpServer class of qt to establish two way communication. I am able to send data from client to server. But am not getting the response back from server i.e my client.cpp never fires readyRead() signal. I have checked using Wireshark that my data from the server is available in specifed port.

I am posting my client.cpp code( Please help) :

```
Client::Client(QObject* parent): QObject(parent)
{
    socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()),
            this, SLOT(startTransfer()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this, SLOT(startRead()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
            this, SLOT(socketError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)) );


}

Client::~Client()
{
    socket->close();
}

void Client::start(QString address, quint16 port)
{
    addr.setAddress(address);
    socket->connectToHost(addr,port,QTcpSocket::ReadWrite);
}

void Client::startTransfer()
{
    printf("Connection established.\n");
    char buffer[1024];
    forever
    {
    printf(">> ");
    gets(buffer);
    int len = strlen(buffer);
    buffer[len] = '\n';
    buffer[len+1] = '\0';
    socket->write(buffer);
    socket->flush();

}
}

void Client::startRead()
{
    cout<<"inside startRead()<<endl";
    while(socket->canReadLine())
       {
       QByteArray ba = socket->readLine();
       if(strcmp(ba.constData(), "!exit\n") == 0)
       {
       socket->disconnectFromHost();
       break;
       }
       printf(">> %s", ba.constData());
}
}

void Client::socketError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError )
    {
    qDebug()<<"error" ;
    }
```

Comment: Please, add server's code: creating QTcpServer, using QTcpSocket etc.

Comment: Why do you have a forever loop there?

Comment: BTW, looping without sleep will make CPU usage 100%, you should rethink your architecture (For example move everything to thread and use `QThread::sleep`).

Comment: @Amartel There won't be 100% CPU usage because there is a read from stdin inside the forever loop there. =)

Comment: @JustAnotherCurious My mistake - read code inattentively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have `forever` loop here. This means that your `Qt` main `eventloop` never gets the control back after you call `startTransfer()`. How do you suppose the `Qt` should run the `startRead()` code if you block your execution thread with infinite loop?

Comment: thanks a ton. I changed my architecture and its working fine now. I am new in coding and never thought that the forever loop may block the further execution.

Answer (score 0):

For Amartel adding the server code:

```
Server::Server(QObject* parent): QObject(parent)
{
 // cout << "Before connect" << endl;
  connect(&server, SIGNAL(newConnection()),
    this, SLOT(acceptConnection()));

  cout << "Listening.." << endl;
  server.listen(QHostAddress::Any, 9999);
//  cout << "Server started.." << endl;
}

Server::~Server()
{
  server.close();
}

void Server::acceptConnection()
{
 // cout << "In acceptConnection" << endl;
  client = server.nextPendingConnection();

  connect(client, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
    this, SLOT(startRead()));
}

void Server::startRead()
{
    while(client->canReadLine())
       {
       QByteArray ba = client->readLine();
       if(strcmp(ba.constData(), "!exit\n") == 0)
       {
       client->disconnectFromHost();
       break;
       }
       printf(">> %s", ba.constData());

       int result = 0;
       bool ack = true;

       result = client->write("I Reached");
       cout<<result<<endl;
       if(result <= 0)
       qDebug("Ack NOT sent to client!!!");
       else
       qDebug("Ack sent to client.");
      // client->write("I Reached");
       client->flush();
}
}
```